# System particles orientation target

Tags: particles, constraints

I need a crowd looking at one target. If i move the target the people change the orientation looking for the target, just the orientation ( i need that the people stay). In tryng with particles obviously, but i can not find where i should put the target. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi! Welcome. Does it work if you put the target on the object you're using for your particles? So if you've got Object A emitting particles of Object B, then go to your (real) Object B and put the target on there?

Comment: Thank you Guys! your comments have been very helpful.
I got it without knowing how, hahaha.
now it's ok, but for the future, you know some link about particles and their orientation,etc explained deeply?
Thanks again!Gassss

Answer (score 1):

You can create a *Force Field > Force* (here its *Strength* is 3) and for the particle system, enable the *Advanced* option and then enable *Rotation > Orientation Axis > Velocity / Hair*:

[image]

Comment: Good one Moonboots!  A handy one for future reference.